# blank screen issue in dotcms admin panel

Tags: dojo, tomcat8, dwr, dotcms, port80

Whenever i am using dotcms 3.3 admin panel, i get blank screen. Actually it is hidding the body.This happens on js issue. Initally i never encountered this issue.

**Solution:** 
To counter this issue i have tried the following solution which has in sense worked successfully,well affecting some other functionalities!!

1) Block port 80:On block this port through firewall, i am able to use dotcms admin panel normally.But this has impacted user creation.With this port blocked user creation throws exception.

If anyone has encounter this issue please help!!

Tried using web server to redirect to app server ,still issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Are there any JS errors in your browser console?  This is normally indicative of a JS call being blocked and so the page never renders.

Comment: yes wezell.There is js error.But the funny thing is , i never created that error.I tried to check if any of my js are conflicting but i didn't find any.This issue is directly linked with js error i agree but the interesting thing is why blocking port 80 rectify blank screen issue!!?pls help me understand the root cause